# How do I get my custom UI component to work correctly with my custom Wordpress theme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm making a couple of themes for Wordpress from scratch. Everything seems to work alright, but when i installed thethe tabs and accordions plugin, a plugin for making accordions with jQuery i realized that jQuery is not working with my templates! I searched a lot, but every method that i try to implement is not working:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?> //Not working
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php wp_head(); ?> // Not working
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> //Not working
```

I even try to make a function in the functions.php file, but i got the same results.
When i look at the code with Chrome it looks like the site is loading jQuery, but for some reason my accordion plugin is not working.
I'm not very familiar with jQuery and Javascript.

I'm working on a localhost and i tried with tewnty eleven and twenty ten themes and everything works well with them. For some reason my themes are not working properly.

Any help would be welcomed.

### Updated on 04/01/2012

After trying everything! I decided to take another way. I used the Shape theme from Thematic, copy all my content over the original content and, voila! Everything it's working properly!
I really don't understand why, but at least it worked.
It's very strange because when i follow the tutorial from Thematic to make a theme like Shape the problem appears again... so, if somebody is getting problems to get jQuery plugins working properly on a WP Theme from scratch i recommend to use the Shape theme as a base theme for start working on.
Hope it helps somebody!

Comment: This question is going to be a guessing game.  See what you can do to boil down the problem to as few steps to repro the issue as possible.  As in, start all over on a theme from scratch (don't throw out your existing theme, of course), and try to find the smallest amount of code you can write to try to get a theme with jQuery working, or show that it doesn't work.

Comment: If you can show us code for some minimal "theme" that repros these problems, we might be better equipped to help you.  Also, have you verified on the client side that the JS for jQuery is getting included correctly?  Is the script tag showing up?  Is the URL in the script tag correct by the time it reaches the client - as in, can you go to that URL and actually find your jQuery script?

Comment: I believe that i'm missing some step to include the jQuery. I can go to the script from the URL and i got jQuery v1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.17.
In my functions.php i got like 34 lines and in my header.php 28. If the code of both archives can help i can put them in here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your trying to include multiple versions of jquery, is that needed? Also I always put wp_head last.  Lastly, and only because I do this all the time, are your files named correctly and in the right folders?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i try to implement those methods not at the same time. I try a lot of things but nothing is working.